# Possible to add a statement to a core file?

Tags: posts, core, wp-list-table

I would like to add one line to a wp core file. Basically on the 'edit.php' page, just right above

```
<?php
include('./admin-footer.php');
```

I would like to add an php include statement...

```
include('./custom-file.php');
```

The custom-file is located inside a plugin, not a theme... so if I write it inside my plugin function.php, the url will be:

```
include( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . '/custom-file.php');
```

Is there some way I can use to add this one line via a function without having to edit the core file?

Thanks!

Comment: There is no reason to do this, use a hook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is zero reason to do this.

1. Why would you need your include in `edit.php`? Just include it in your plugin.
2. If for some reason you need to hook into the `edit.php` page (hard to tell what you're doing), you can use,

   ```
   add_action( 'load-edit.php', 'your_function' );
   ```

---

[image]

Comment: Hi Wyck, I do not want to edit the core files. What I want to do is add a function in my plugin to add a include statement to the edit.php file. Reason for this is because I am trying to achieve is add the QuickPress widget to the edit.php page. I was able to achieve this, but the only way I know how to add it is to place the include line in the edit.php page (just to test). Once this was accomplished, I am trying to find a way to add the include line via a function. Here is an image of what I am trying to achieve. http://i.imgur.com/QKHkEqs.jpg The code works, it's just how to add it.

Comment: Adding an include statement to a core file is considered editing a core file..in other words don't do it. Instead ask "how can I include a custom widget on the edit page" in a new question or something. The `action` I gave above for example.

Comment: Thanks for the help BTW Wyck. This works great. The function loads additional html. Is there a way to make the code load at the bottom of the page? Currently it loads just right below the opening <body> tag. I am trying to make it load just above the <footer>. Thanks!

Comment: I see, thanks for the clarification. I guess I was approaching this wrong, as I duped the QuickPress into a new widget file. But I was adding it to the edit.pgp via a include statement.

Comment: To add it under I don't know off the top of my head you will have to check or ask another question, or maybe hook into `admin_footer` and check if the requested page is `edit.php` in the function.

Comment: You might hate me for this, but this is the code I am using now. I know that you mentioned using "include" is considered hacking the core, but is there another way I can load the file? And to accept the answer, do I just click on the checkmark? Thanks. - Edit. This might be easier to look at: http://pastebin.com/Xsq3ymzV

Comment: that's not hacking core :) that is using a hook in your plugin or theme to add your code, the core is untouched. yes the check-mark. Have a read of this: http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't modify core files. All modifications will be deleted whenever you update WordPress.

Depending upon your needs you can use an [action](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/) like `admin_footer` or a filter like `admin_footer_text`. This page on [Creating Admin Themes](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Admin_Themes) gives you an example on how to use both.

Comment: Hi rrikesh, Yes, I do not want to modify the core file. I would prefer to add an action to a function that targets only the edit.php file. If I specify an action for the admin_footer, is there a way to make the code display only on the edit.php page? Thanks!

Comment: This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14380306/wordpress-how-to-hook-into-edit-php